# Check to see if any value of array1 is contained in array2 with built-in function? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I tried in_array and array_search. Even when BOTH values are contained in the searched array, I got false values back. It goes without saying, but I'll say it anyway, that if you remove 'marmotte' from `$search_this_array`, the functions still return false.

This is not an emergency, since I can just use in_array() twice to get the result. But I am surprised if there is no built-in way to do it at once... perhaps array intersect?

```
$search_this_array = array('bug','dog','cat','marmotte');
$search_with_array = array('bug','marmotte');
if(in_array($search_with_array,$search_this_array) == true) echo '
in_array = ==true
';
else echo '
in_array === false
';
if(array_search($search_with_array,$search_this_array) == true) echo '
array_search===true
';
else echo '
array_search === false
';
```

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself: [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Comment: Specifically, you want (array_intersect($array1, $array2) !== array()).